# Наследование в Js, базовые свойства в отдельной функции

Tags: javascript, наследование

Друзья, имеется функция LineObject(); есть объекты-"дети", у которых меняются размеры и положение. Есть update(), в которой прописаны общие вещи для всех "детей" (сейчас они для каждого ребенка отдельно). Никак не могу в документациях найти аналог, как можно с помощью наследования упростить громоздкость, если update() и LineObject() разные функции. Заранее спасибо.

```
function update()
        {
            if (canvas.height < obj1.pos_y)
                {
                    obj1.pos_y = 0;
                }

            if (canvas.height < obj2.pos_y)
                {
                    obj2.pos_y = 0;
                }

            if (canvas.height < obj3.pos_y)
                {
                    obj3.pos_y = 0;
                }

            if (canvas.height < obj4.pos_y)
                {
                    obj4.pos_y = 0;
                }

            if (canvas.height < obj5.pos_y)
                {
                    obj5.pos_y = 0;
                }

            obj1.pos_y += obj1.speed;
            obj2.pos_y += obj2.speed;
            obj3.pos_y += obj3.speed;
            obj4.pos_y += obj4.speed;
            obj5.pos_y += obj5.speed;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/or2du4r3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По данному вопросу:

1. Ваш код не использует наследование... и на данном этапе, *не нуждается* в нем.
   Если упрощенно, наследование - это когда один класс расширяет/переопределяет свойства другого. У Вас же, экземпляры (не "дети"!) одного и того же класса... с абсолютно одинаковой логикой. Так что, незачем впустую усложнять.
2. Используйте массив объектов и цикл, вместо 6 отдельных переменных (половина из которых, в вашем коде даже не объявлена). Пример с массивом ниже, в примере под спойлером.

```js
const TIMEOUT = 40;

var canvas, context,
    lines = Array(6),
    stTime = 0,
    r = 180,
    g = 189,
    b = 211;
window.onload = main;

function main() {
  init();
  animate();
  changeColor(); 
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // если объектов будет больше, то здесь тоже потребуется цикл. Пока что оставил как есть
  lines[0] = new LineObject(290, 0, 45);
  lines[1] = new LineObject(290, 0, 45);
  lines[2] = new LineObject(480, 80, 50);
  lines[3] = new LineObject(50, 150, 40);
  lines[4] = new LineObject(300, 200, 30);
  lines[5] = new LineObject(100, 65, 35);
}

// проверка Y-позиции и вызов отрисовки в одной функции - нет смысла их дробить. 
function animate(time) {
  if (time - stTime >= TIMEOUT) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      // проверяем Y
      if (lines[i].pos_y - lines[i].size > canvas.height)
        lines[i].pos_y = -lines[i].size;
      else
        lines[i].pos_y += lines[i].speed; 
      // рисуем 
      lines[i].draw();
    }
    stTime = time; 
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);  // как уже говорил Вам ранее: не используйте setTimeout() для анимации!
}

function changeColor() {
  if (r === 180 && g === 189 && b === 211) {
    r = 251;
    g = 253;
    b = 217;
  } else {
    r = 180;
    g = 189;
    b = 211;
  }
  setTimeout(changeColor, 300);
}


function LineObject(pos_x, pos_y, size) {
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  this.pos_x = pos_x;
  this.pos_y = pos_y;
  this.width = 2;
  this.size = size;
  this.speed = 2;
  this.addheight = Math.sin(Math.PI / 4) * (this.size / 2);

  this.draw = function() {    // TODO: лучше переписать весь этот ужас
    const drawLine = () => {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x1, y1);
      context.lineTo(x2, y2);
      context.stroke();
    }; 
    const s1  = this.size * 0.098,  // такие оптимизашки (и те что ниже, в выражениях) - помогают, но не идеальны: 
          s14 = this.size * 0.14,   //  вместо того чтобы на каждом кадре считать всю эту фигню, 
          s31 = this.size * 0.314,  //  лучше использовать константную матрицу коэффициентов для компактного 
          s22 = this.size * 0.22,   //  и очень быстрого цикличного вычисления [posX,posY] => [x1,y1,x2,y2] 
          s50 = this.size * 0.50;
    let x1, y1, x2, y2, buf;
    context.strokeStyle = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}`;
    // основные лучи "снежинок"
    x1 = x2 = this.pos_x; 
    y2 = this.pos_y; y1 = y2 + this.size; 
    drawLine(); 
    x1 += s50; x2 -= s50;
    y1 = y2 = this.pos_y + s50;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = this.pos_x - this.addheight; x2 = this.pos_x + this.addheight; 
    buf = this.pos_y + s50; 
    y1 = buf - this.addheight; y2 = buf + this.addheight; 
    drawLine(); 
    buf = x1; x1 = x2; x2 = buf; 
    drawLine(); 
    // хреньки на кончиках лучей 
    x1 = x2 = this.pos_x - s22;
    y1 = this.pos_y + s14; y2 = y1 + s14; 
    drawLine(); 
    y2 = this.pos_y + s50 + s22; y1 = y2 + s14; 
    drawLine(); 
    x2 = this.pos_x - s22; x1 = x2 - s14; 
    y1 = y2 = this.pos_y + s14 * 2;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = x2 = this.pos_x + s22;
    y1 = this.pos_y + s14; y2 = y1 + s14; 
    drawLine(); 
    x2 = this.pos_x + s22; x1 = x2 + s14; 
    y1 = y2; 
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = this.pos_x - s22; x2 = x1 - s14;
    y1 = y2 = this.pos_y + s50 + s22;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = x2 = this.pos_x + s22; y2 += s14;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = this.pos_x + s22; x2 = x1 + s14;
    y1 = y2 = this.pos_y + s50 + s22;
    drawLine(); 
    x2 = this.pos_x, x1 = x2 - s1;
    y1 = this.pos_y + s1; y2 = y1 + s1;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = x2 + s1; 
    y1 = this.pos_y + s1; y2 = y1 + s1;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = x2 - s1;
    y2 = this.pos_y + s50 + s31; y1 = y2 + s1;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = x2 + s1; 
    drawLine();
    x1 = x2 - s31; x2 = x1 - s1;
    y1 = this.pos_y + s50; y2 = y1 - s1;
    drawLine(); 
    y2 = y1 + s1;
    drawLine(); 
    x1 = this.pos_x + s31; x2 = x1 + s1;
    drawLine();
    y2 = y1 - s1;
    drawLine(); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="CanvasContainer" id="CanvasContainer" style="">
   <img id="pic" src="https://i.imgur.com/TsfD54q.jpg" width="600">
   <canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="600" height="375" style="position:absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Относительно примера. Частично я исправил и оптимизировал ваше творение, но метод `draw` - особая история. Хотя он стал ощутимо быстрее и где-то вдвое компактнее по символам, это не решило его проблем: там хромает не совсем JS, а  ***сам подход*** к реализации алгоритма. Оптимальнее всего будет эту функцию полностью переделать. Советую прописать матрицу коэффициентов координат (для каждой линии), и при отрисовке просто умножать координаты на эти коэффициенты, в цикле. Примерно такой же подход используется в частотных фильтрах графических редакторов (только там вместо линий пиксели)... он работает достаточно хорошо и быстро.
Продублировал это в комментариях к коду.

*p.s.: Мы с Вами ~2 месяца назад об этих снежинках уже беседовали, на другом ресурсе :D*

Comment: спасибо Вам, помню-помню, с наследованием до сего не работала, но любой уважающий себя front обязан его знать.

Comment: @Наташа, судя по fiddle, Вам сначала ***необходимо*** освоить циклы. Они - краеугольный камень всех машинных вычислений, и без циклов невозможно эффективное программирование. Пока не изучены самые основы, нет смысла даже пробовать залезть в ООП (аксиома: попытки "перешагнуть" базовые знания, всегда отбрасывают назад... это напряжное и потное топтание на одном месте, вместо плавного и уверенного движения вперед).

Comment: _"наследованием ... любой уважающий себя front обязан его знать"_ - в более чем половине реальных задач вакуумносферического JS'ера, написание своих классов с наследованием, попросту не требуется. А вот работа со структурами данных (в число которых входят и массивы, и DOM) необходима в ~90..100% случаев. Подумайте, правильно ли расставлены ваши приоритеты.

Comment: да, большое спасибо, я с JS работаю несколько месяцев, до этого html, css, jquery, некоторые функции Canvas, ну и еще мелочь про фронту. Начала рисовать для себя, чтобы изучать глубже canvas, выяснилось, что азы js плохо знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Всё уже придумано: классы и наследования:

```js
class Batya {
  sayMyName() {
    console.info(`My name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

class Child extends Batya {
  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let children = [];

[...Array(10)].forEach((_, i) => children.push(new Child(`#${i + 1}`)));

children.forEach(ch => ch.sayMyName());
```